# Inheritante and class problems in python

Tags: python, class

First of all, excuse my english.

I am trying to perform a simple class application in python. The concept is something like this.

```
    class Auth:
            def __init__(self, username, password):
                self.username = username
                self.password = password
            def connect(self):
                """here is the code for connecting into X server"""
                pass

    class Manager(Auth):
        """used for search auctions, for example"""
        def __init__(self, username, password):
            Auth.__init__(self, username, password)
        def pile(self):
            y = self.some_search_into_a_server()
            for x in y:
                yield Auction(x)
        def buy(self):
            """buy method for using by auction"""
            pass

    class Auction:
        def __init__(self, auction):
            self.id = auction["id"]
            self.some_data = auction["some_data"]
```

well, the point here is that I want to do is something like this:

```
manager = Manager('user@example.com', 'a_very_secure_password')
for auction in manager.pile():
    auction.buy()
```

the problem here is: How can I bring about that Manager inherits from Auction and that Aucion uses method buy?

Comment: This is not how you use inheritance.

Comment: yes it is the only way to do, incase you are telling something else

Comment: `buy` should probably be on `Auction` to begin with.  And you probably want a `User` that has an `Auth` and one or more `Auctions` attached to it (or alternatively, each `Auction` has a `User` with an `Auth`).  Basically, there are fundamental design issues here, and without more information on what you are trying to do at a higher level, providing a meaningful answer is nearly impossible.

Comment: I've edited the post, notice the Auction(x) object returns now in pile() method. The point is that if I do Auction inherits from Manager instantiaing it will produce another Authentication again.

Comment: `Manager.__init__()` is superfluous.  It's not clear what information `buy()` needs to operate; I'd guess the `Auction` ID and the `Auth` information, but that's not clear from the code.  `some_search_into_a_server()` is not even stubbed, and `connect()` is never called.  How are these pieces supposed to be linked together, and what is each piece responsible for in the larger scope of the whole program?  Yes, `Auction` can have a `manager` and a `buy()` that calls it's own `Manager`'s `buy()`, but that only opens more questions about why you want to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if X **is a** Y , then you need ***inheritence***, for example a **dog** is an **animal** , or a **poodle** is a **dog**

if X **has a** Y, then you need ***membership***, for example a **dog** has an **owner**, or a **store** has **customers**.

based on the fact that an auction **HAS A** manager. You likely would like membership rather than inheritence

```
class Auction:
    def __init__(self, manager,auction):
        self.id = auction["id"]
        self.manager = manager
        self.some_data = auction["some_data"]
    def buy(self):
          return self.manager.buy()

class Manager(Auth):
    """used for search auctions, for example"""
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        Auth.__init__(self, username, password)
    def pile(self):
        y = self.some_search_into_a_server()
        for x in y:
            yield Auction(self,x)
    def buy(self):
        """buy method for using by auction"""
        pass

manager = Manager('user@example.com', 'a_very_secure_password')
for auction in manager.pile():
    auction.buy()
```